# How do I make a class, which I can't change, implement an interface?

Tags: java, interface, adapter, instanceof, proxy-classes

I have a class from another library that is closed-source, but I want to be able to use an interface for it. The reason being that I don't want to do `instanceof` checks or `null`-checks everywhere, but I also don't want to extend the existing class.

For example, let's say I have this code:

```
public class Example {

    // QuietFoo is from another library that I can't change
    private static QuietFoo quietFoo;
    // LoudFoo is my own code and is meant to replace QuietFoo
    private static LoudFoo loudFoo;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        handle(foo);
    }

    private static void handle(Object foo) {
        if (foo instanceof QuietFoo)
            ((QuietFoo) foo).bar();
        else if (foo instanceof LoudFoo)
            ((LoudFoo) foo).bar();
    }
}
```

I can't change `QuietFoo`:

```
public class QuietFoo {

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("bar");
    }
}
```

But I *can* change `LoudFoo`:

```
public class LoudFoo {

    public void bar() {
        System.out.println("BAR!!");
    }
}
```

The problem is, there may be many other implementations of `bar` in many classes, and there may be more methods than just `bar`, so not only would my `handle` method get slow and ugly with lots of `instanceof` statements, but I would have to write one of these handle methods for each method on `QuietFoo` and `LoudFoo`. Extending isn't a viable solution because it violates the whole *is-a* contract since `LoudFoo` is not a `QuietFoo`.

Basically, given `Foo`:

```
public interface Foo {
    void bar();
}
```

How can I make `QuietFoo` implement `Foo` without changing its source so I don't have to do casting and `instanceof` calls everywhere in my code?

Comment: Before anyone gives me flak: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @Gamb Read that blog post in my comment -.- And if you mouse over the "x mins ago", you'll see that technically, it was exactly the same time :3

Comment: Ah, okay. When you post a question, you have the option to "Answer your own question" (a checkbox at the bottom of [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)) that will also give you a place to enter the answer. That's how I got it to be submitted at the exact same time. I used "you" so that people would view it conversationally, making it an easier read.

Comment: I know that. It turns this into a wiki entry rather than a question-answer(IMHO). No worries, it's a cool answer, but my comment seems to belong to meta as a question rather than here :)

Comment: @Gamb If you ask a question on meta, let me know what you find out.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1. Using an adapter pattern
2. Using [`Proxy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)

The adapter approach will be simpler but less flexible, and the `Proxy` approach will be more complex but more flexible. Even though the `Proxy` approach is more complex, that complexity is all restricted to a couple of classes.

---

**Adapter**

The [adapter pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/adapter-pattern.html) is simple. For your example, it would just be one class, like so:

```
public class QuietFooAdapter implements Foo {

    private QuietFoo quietFoo;

    public QuietFooAdapter(QuietFoo quietFoo) {
        this.quietFoo = quietFoo;
    }

    public void bar() {
        quietFoo.bar();
    }
}
```

Then to use it:

```
Foo foo = new QuietFooAdapter(new QuietFoo());
foo.bar();
```

This is good, but if you have more than one class to make an adapter for, this can be tedious since you'll need a new adapter for each class you have to wrap.

---

**Java's `Proxy` Class**

`Proxy` is a native Java class that's part of the reflection libraries that will allow you to create a more generic, reflective solution. It involves 3 parts:

1. The interface (in this case, `Foo`)
2. The [`InvocationHandler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationHandler.html)
3. Creation of the proxy ([`Proxy.newProxyInstance`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html#newProxyInstance%28java.lang.ClassLoader,%20java.lang.Class%5B%5D,%20java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler%29))

We already have the interface, so we're fine there.

The `InvocationHandler` is where we do our "auto-adapting" via reflection:

```
public class AdapterInvocationHandler implements InvocationHandler {

    private Object target;
    private Class<?> targetClass;

    public AdapterInvocationHandler(Object target) {
        this.target = target;
        targetClass = target.getClass();
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method method, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        try {
            Method targetMethod = targetClass.getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
            if (!method.getReturnType().isAssignableFrom(targetMethod.getReturnType()))
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Target (" + target.getClass().getName() + ") does not support: " + method.toGenericString());
            return targetMethod.invoke(target, args);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException ex) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Target (" + target.getClass().getName() + ") does not support: " + method.toGenericString());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Target (" + target.getClass().getName() + ") does not declare method to be public: " + method.toGenericString());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException ex) {
            // May throw a NullPointerException if there is no target exception
            throw ex.getTargetException();
        }
    }
}
```

The important code here is in the `try` block. This will handle the process of adapting any method calls that are called on the proxy to the inner `target` object. If a method is called on the interface that isn't supported (non-`public`, wrong return type, or just flat out doesn't exist), then we throw an `UnsupportedOperationException`. If we catch an `InvocationTargetException`, we rethrow the exception that caused it via `InvocationTargetException.getTargetException`. This occurs when the method we called reflectively throws an exception. Java wraps it in a new exception and throws that new exception.

Next, we need something to create the adapters:

```
public class AdapterFactory {

    public static <T> T createAdapter(Object target, Class<T> interfaceClass) {
        if (!interfaceClass.isInterface())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Must be an interface: " + interfaceClass.getName());
        return (T) Proxy.newProxyInstance(null, new Class<?>[] { interfaceClass }, new AdapterInvocationHandler(target));
    }
}
```

You could also nest the `AdapterInvocationHandler` class in the `AdapterFactory` class, if you like, so that everything is self-contained in `AdapterFactory`.

Then to use it:

```
Foo foo = AdapterFactory.createAdapter(new QuietFoo(), Foo.class);
foo.bar();
```

This approach requires more code than implementing a single adapter, but will be generic enough that it can be used to create auto-adapters for any class and interface pair, not just the `QuietFoo` and `Foo` example. Granted, this method uses reflection (the `Proxy` class uses reflection, as does our `InvocationHandler`), which *can* be slower, but recent improvements in the JVM have made reflection much faster than it used to be.

Comment: +1 Interesting Reflection approach (reflection enthusiast here).